# Sorting 2D by rank

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I want to sort my 2D array to match the rank of another array

I have tried the `sorted()` and `sort()` function and it's not working. I am not sure if I am formatting it wrong or what is the best way to do it.

```
array = (32,96)
ranked =  [57, 23, 68, 58, 25, 91, 70, 83, 77, 75, 89, 34, 49, 79, 66, 54, 67,
       44, 63, 52, 46, 20, 64, 10, 80, 33, 30, 29, 28, 26, 17, 27, 50, 51,
       92, 86, 69, 47,  0,  7,  3, 85, 18, 11, 13, 53,  8, 78, 82, 81, 14,
       74, 59, 32, 42, 39,  1, 31, 36, 19, 24,  5, 38,  9, 73, 71, 76, 87,
       41, 55, 94, 93, 84, 16, 90, 62, 48, 43, 72, 95, 65, 45, 61, 22, 21,
       15, 37, 88,  2, 40, 56,  6, 12, 60,  4, 35]
sortedarray = sorted(array,ranked)
```

for the code above i get an error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

ranked has 96 values that correspond to the second dimension in the original array.

Comment: Won't `array[:,ranked]` do the job?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to be sorting the other dimension of the array

Comment: If you could, please show us a minimal sample and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the second dimension of `array`, you can first make an empty `sortedarray` of shape (32, 96) and then fill in the new array in the ordered specified by `ranked`. Here is the code using random values for `array`:

```
array = np.random.random((32,96))
ranked =  [57, 23, 68, 58, 25, 91, 70, 83, 77, 75, 89, 34, 49, 79, 66, 54, 67,
       44, 63, 52, 46, 20, 64, 10, 80, 33, 30, 29, 28, 26, 17, 27, 50, 51,
       92, 86, 69, 47,  0,  7,  3, 85, 18, 11, 13, 53,  8, 78, 82, 81, 14,
       74, 59, 32, 42, 39,  1, 31, 36, 19, 24,  5, 38,  9, 73, 71, 76, 87,
       41, 55, 94, 93, 84, 16, 90, 62, 48, 43, 72, 95, 65, 45, 61, 22, 21,
       15, 37, 88,  2, 40, 56,  6, 12, 60,  4, 35]

sortedarray = np.zeros(np.shape(array))
sortedarray[:, ranked] = array
```